# i'm trying to send data from activity to fragment but i get this error, any can help please?

Tags: android, android-fragments

this the error I got [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntxwH.png)

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
TextView profileNames,ProfileRegNumber;
String regnumber;
String Student_URL ="http://192.168.43.244/ULKandroid/student.php";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
    //HomeActivity homeActivity = new HomeActivity();
    profileNames = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileNames);
    ProfileRegNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileRegNo);

    String n = this.getArguments().getString("names");
    String r = this.getArguments().getString("reg");

    profileNames.setText(n);
    ProfileRegNumber.setText(r);

    return v;
}
```

}

so there is the same error I get that looks like this

> 11-08 11:54:12.604 4154-4154/cards.inkuge.com.ulkstudent
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: cards.inkuge.com.ulkstudent, PID: 4154
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at cards.inkuge.com.ulkstudent.Fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:46)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

1. List item

and is that an Activity Where Sets an Arguments

```
else {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                        bundle.putString("names",jsonObject.getString("student_names"));
                                        bundle.putString("reg",jsonObject.getString("regnumber_student"));
                                        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                                        bundle.putString("names",jsonObject.getString("student_names"));
                                        bundle.putString("reg",jsonObject.getString("regnumber_student"));
                                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        clear();
                                        finish();
                                    }
```

Comment: Post the code where you pass "names" and "reg" to the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your fragment something like this:

```
 public static ProfileFragment NewInstance(String names, String reg) {
    ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("names", names);
    bundle.putString("reg", reg);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

Also be sure that you have constructor like this

```
 public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

Define global variables in this fragment like this:

```
private String _names;
private String _reg;
```

Override onCreate method like this:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getArguments() != null) {
        _names= getArguments().getString("names");
        _reg= getArguments().getString("reg");
    }
}
```

then in your OnCrateView method set text like this:

```
profileNames.setText(_names);
ProfileRegNumber.setText(_reg);
```

And in Activity create fragment like this.

```
private void replaceFragmentInternal(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_fragment, R.anim.exit_fragment);

            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.frameLayoutHolder, fragment)
                    .commit();
    }


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        replaceFragmentInternal(ProfileFragment.NewInstance(names,reg));
}
```